# the $velocityCount in velocity2.0 not work

Tags: java, velocity

when i update the velocity from 1.7 to 2.0,the $velocityCount not working,and got the error:

```
[org.apache.velocity.rendering] - Left side ($velocityCount) of comparison operation has null value
```

what happen?

My code is as follow:

```
"images": [
       #foreach($image in $cl.images)
        #if($velocityCount <= 3)
        #set($img = $cot.encryptUrlForTrans($image.imageUrl))
        #set($_img = "http://tf.example.com/tc/img/")
        #if($velocityCount != 1),#end
        {
           "url": "$_img$img?enable=&w=120&h=80&cut=",
           "width": 120,
           "height": 80
         }
     #end
     #end
     ]
```

And the line `#set($img = $cot.encryptUrlForTrans($image.imageUrl))` have got the NullPointerException ? if this can be executed the $image must be not null  ,i don't know the error how happen? because the method encryptUrlForTrans(null) has right return value.

Comment: Can you add the code how it is called ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to follow [upgrading instructions](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/2.0/upgrading.html) and check logs for previous errors.

There's a need for changing dependencies and also

> To maximize backward compatibility with Velocity 1.x,
>   be sure to include the following lines in your Velocity configuration:
>
> runtime.conversion.handler = none space.gobbling = bc

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The $velocityCount  cann't be used in velocity2.0?

Comment: Do you use Apache Cayenne ? It contains in velocity.properties `directive.foreach.counter.name = velocityCount`

Answer (score 1):

I am using 2.0, $velocityCount does not work, but both of $foreach.index and $foreach.count work.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `$foreach.index` for a zero-based index, or `$foreach.count` for a 1-based counter.

Of course, check the [upgrading instructions](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/2.0/upgrading.html) as suggested by user7294900.